# Calculating position/distance of point on arc of circle

Tags: geometry, circles, triangles

I'm having a hard time trying to wrap my head around this problem.

Imagine a line of length $A+B$ with center $C$, with a circle with $d = A+B$ with center at $C$.
Now imagine drawing a line at $90^{\circ}$ from an arbitrary point, $D$, along the line $A+B$, which intersects the circle at point $E$.
How could one calculate the distance between $D$ and $E$ the point?

This is kinda hard to explain, as English is not my first language, so please refer to picture for an example.

[image: Explanatory image]

Feel free to help me tag this appropriately.

Comment: You are looking for $ED$?

Comment: @BabakS. Yes, the distance between those two points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pithagora's theorem tells you that
$$CD^2+DE^2 = \left(\frac{AB}{2}\right)^2$$

Comment: We can also assume that $CD$ is 2 on this diagram and that $CE=\frac{AB}2=CB=AC$

Comment: Sweet... Thanks for reminding me of this fundamental theorem! (It has been a VERY long while since I dabbled with geometry... Not since grade school, if I recall correctly...) This is what I ended up with: $DE = \sqrt{\left (\frac{AB}{2}\right )^2-CD^2}$. Again, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

there is this possibility too.

BD/DE=DE/AD

and DE²=BD*DA